# In Jest, how do I mock a Promise of void?

Tags: typescript, promise, mocking, void, ts-jest

I'm using Jest and Typescript.  I have a async function that returns nothing (void).  How do I mock returning void?  I tried the below

```
const myMockFn = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(void));
jest.mock('../config', () => ({
  setup: async () =>
  myMockFn(),
}));
```

but I get the compilation error

```
Expression expected.
```

related to "Promise.resolve(void)".

Comment: Should just be `Promise.resolve()` instead of `Promise.resolve(void)`

Comment: Try to avoid using `void`  operator

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) used here in `value` position is javascript operator. It is a unary operator i.e. it accepts a single argument. Thus the error.

[`void`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void) as a typescript type should be used in `type` position to express that function return value will not be observed.

```ts
const myMockFn = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());
```

That's enough to mock a function with `Promise<void>` return type.

Answer (score 8):

You can mock a function that returns `Promise<void>` with:

```
jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined)
```

If you try to capture the return value of a `void` function, you get `undefined`:

```
function foo(): void {
  console.log('foo called');
}

console.log(foo());

// foo called
// undefined
```

Additionally, `Promise<void>` appears to be the same as `Promise<undefined>`:

```
console.log(Promise.resolve());
// Promise { undefined }

console.log(Promise.resolve(undefined));
// Promise { undefined }
```

`undefined` is compatible with `void` and can be the resolved value:

```
interface Bar {
  foo(): Promise<void>;
}

describe('StackOverflow', () => {
  test('mock Promise<void>', async () => {
    const mockBar: Bar = {
      foo: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(undefined),
    };
    await mockBar.foo();
  });
});
```

Comment: Or to simplify the expression even further, `jest.fn().mockResolvedValue()`.

Comment: @PriiduNeemre _Expected 1 argument._

Comment: @Heisenberg: which defaults to `undefined` when you omit it.

Comment: @PriiduNeemre the argument has no default value, at least not in typescript , the definition is : `mockResolvedValue(value: ResolvedValue<T>)` and calling it with no parameter causes error `TS2554`

Comment: @Heisenberg: Ah, yes. In TypeScript, it is a mandatory parameter and would probably work like this for `void` functions only.